# Flutter How to animate marker smoothly?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, mobile

I'm developing custom marker on google map using Flutter.

I just want to know about Marker.

Can I implement marker animation smootly??

ex. 
LatLng(xx.xxxxxxx) => LatLng(yy.yyyyyyy) 
when marker move, it has to move smoothly.

please refer to this image.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31180

Comment: Try my answer. This package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker

Answer (score 1):

Try this  [new package - Animarker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker) to animate marker over the Google Maps.

```
_latLngStream.getLatLngInterpolation().listen
```

Comment: lib is not so good. it has many issues.